# Rename voice-mail tag to voicemail?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do you think that would be an improvement?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Google Ngrams: voicemail,voice-mail,voice mail]

In books, “voicemail” is gaining but “voice mail” is still the dominant form. Books do tend to lag a few years behind Internet usage, but the difference is large enough that I favor keeping [voice-mail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-mail).

For a borderline case in terms of popularity, the hyphened form is preferable, because it's easier to parse. So this speaks in favor of [voice-mail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-mail) too.

On the other hand, the tag name on other Stack Exchange sites is always unhyphenated: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/voicemail), [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/voicemail), [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/voicemail), [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/tags/voicemail), [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tags/voicemail). That's a good argument for going with the flock (even if I think the flock made the wrong choice). Even if we end up sticking with [voice-mail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-mail), I've created a [voicemail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voicemail) synonym for the sake of migrations.

Comment: Two ?'s: (1) Is that a google usage chart? (2) What is meant by "easier to parse"?  FWIW, I see "voicemail" regularly, "voice mail" occasionally, but "voice-mail" almost never... it just looks weird :)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard (1) It's a Google Ngrams chart, just follow the link. (2) “Voice mail” is easier to read than “voicemail”, especially for people who are not native English speakers. (3) Yes, the chart does show “voice-mail” as a clear minority, what we're debating is “voice mail” vs “voicemail”.

Comment: Your comment about non-native English speakers is very interesting.  Do you happen to have any sort of reference for that... no big deal if you don't... from a science (linguistics) point of view, I would be interested in reading more.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend renaming the `voice-mail` tag to `voicemail`.

From what I've seen, `voicemail` is the more common spelling.

`E-mail` was once popular, but now most people use `email`.